# 日本語に違和感: ユーザープロフィール: 「最近の名前」

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

URL例: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/users/30/ento

[image: 最近の名前]

違和感/間違いがある箇所:

- 最近の名前

  - ??
- 1 件の最近の表示名

  - ??
- 最終使用名

  - 最終使用日時

Comment: この画面をどこにクリックすれば表示されますか？

Comment: @jmac 「最近の名前 1」の「1」をクリックすると表示されます

Comment: Transifexに移行済みということで完了にします

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transifexにそれらしい文があったので翻訳案を出しました。

https://www.transifex.com/projects/p/stack-overflow-ja/translate/#ja/english/40288732?comment=%2Fq%2F247%2F

ここで言う`recent`はどの程度なのだろうと思ったら、[SEメタ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116960)に回答が。

> is limited to recent names, where "recent" currently means "90 days" - which should be plenty to avoid confusion between users in most cases